# Query hangs using parameter in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I am having difficulty understanding a query here.
My query ultimately returns a result set in a report where you can specify a Person in the parameter to view their data.
I am joining my Dimension table to my Employee table to return the Name from the Employee table. It looks something like this

```
Declare @PM varchar(30)
Set @PM = 'John Smith'

SELECT....FullName, EmployeeID, .... 
FROM...
Inner Join EmployeesT on emp.EmployeeNumber = DimP.PersonID
WHERE FullName in (@PM)
```

**Note: My Employee table is in nvarchar and Dimension is is varchar but i dont think that matters as the join still works.**

Now, I set a parameter up at the top for testing.

Here is my issue: If I switch the `WHERE` clause to say `WHERE DimP.PersonID IN ('12345')` my query takes 3 seconds to run. When I change the query to `WHERE FullName in (@PM)` the query is taking forever to run; it hangs and runs for 5+ minuets. Has anyone experienced a similar issue?

The result set produces the correct data with multiple "people" and I want to test this by specifying a person, not an id, but  when I change the parameter to the Name the query hangs..

Comment: The performance issue is more related to the table structure and indexes. Also if you are only passing in one name why are you not simply putting "WHERE FullName = @PM"?

Comment: I tried this and had the same issue. It was resolved by adding the following CASE statement below. I have no idea why

Comment: I'm unsure whether the case statement is correct as it doesn't seem to be returning anything. You should probably post the full query in the question. Additionally, the performance issue may be a result of a bad execution plan. See discussion here: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/tuning-stored-procedures-local-variables-problems/

Answer (score 1):

It might be parameter sniffing.  It is hanging onto the optimized execution plan for another parameter value.
Try using OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@parm UNKNOWN)) at the end of your query.

```
Declare @PM varchar(30)
Set @PM = 'John Smith'

SELECT....FullName, EmployeeID, .... 
FROM...
Inner Join EmployeesT on emp.EmployeeNumber = DimP.PersonID
WHERE FullName in (@PM)

OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@PM UNKNOWN))
```

Answer (score 0):

My coworker was able to solve this, she used

```
WHERE emp.empNumber = (CASE WHEN emp.FullName IN (@PM) )
```

Comment: Was that the exact syntax she used because pretty sure that's just going to error out if you add that on...unless that's the results you want? check out [this blog](http://www.sqldoubleg.com/2016/03/03/fast-with-values-slow-with-variables/) post for a potential reason for the slowdown.

Comment: @Shaneis The query should have been running in less than 5 seconds. Using IN PM or emp.empNumber = PM would hang and take over 5 mins. Using this case statement seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: Resolve the issue of it taking over 5 minutes to run? I've no doubt as the last time I checked, errors get returned straight away.
If this solved your timing issue, that's great! 
But the full CASE syntax did, not what you have there.
`CASE input_expression 
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END`

Comment: The syntax after a few other `AND` looks like:

`Declare @PM varchar(50);
Set @PM = 'John Smith';
....WHERE....`

`AND (emp.EmpNumber = (CASE
                          WHEN emp.FullName IN(@PM)
                          THEN emp.empNumber
                          ELSE 0
                      END))`